# Convert CSS to React.js Style

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, elementor

I am using Elementor as a REST Api and I am getting bunch of strings in React side in this shape :

```
selector a {
    width: 189px;
    line-height: 29px;
}
```

Is there any library that can convert CSS with Pseudo to inline style in React?
I tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-to-js library but it doesn't support brackets and Pseudo

Comment: Can you post some more examples of the api return? Are they in an object? Or is just a simply string with all the css rules?

Comment: @Arm144 yes it is just a simple string with all the css rules

Answer (score 0):

So if what you want to do is apply this styles when you receive the response, you can do something like this with vanilla JS

```js
var styleTxt=".container {background-color:grey;color:orange;width:100px;} footer {heigth: 50px;background-color:black} button {color:white; font-size: 15px; border: 1px solid white; background: transparent}"

setTimeout(()=>{
  var element = document.createElement('style');
  element.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
  element.innerHTML = styleTxt;
  document.head.append(element);
}, 2000)
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Test for dinamic css</span>
  <footer>
    <button>Test</button>
  </footer>
</div>
```

**styleTxt** will be the response of the call.

I just put the timeout so you can see the before and after :)